# How to define ViewModel for Array type inputs

Tags: c#, model-view-controller

My HTML is as following.

```
 <div class="input-group phone-input">
  <span class="input-group-btn">
 ...
 <input type="hidden" name="phone[1][type]" class="type-input" value="" />
 <input type="text" name="phone[1][number]" class="form-control k-textbox" placeholder="+1 (999) 999 9999" />
        ...
```

My View Model is as Following.

```
 public class PhoneNumberDTO
    {
        public int type { get; set; }
        public string number { get; set; }


    }

 public class AccountCreationDTO
    {
    ....


        public IList<PhoneNumberDTO> phone { get; set; }
    }
```

But It do not work. but in request parameters it passes to server as listed below.

phone[1][type]  291910
phone[1][number]    2500000

Comment: How are you passing the inputs to the server? I don't understand the essence of `AccountCreationDTO`.

Comment: AccountCreationDTO is the Viewmodel.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you're using ASP.NET MVC.

I assume your action looks similar to this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index(AccountCreationDTO accountCreationDTO)
{
    return View();
}
```

I think you should remove the second square brackets from `input` name, like this.

```
<input name="phone[0].type" value="0" />
<input name="phone[0].number" value="0" />
<input name="phone[1].type" value="1" />
<input name="phone[1].number" value="1" />
```

Then the list comes in correctly:
[image: Here]

Let me know if this solves your issue. Although I think it's better to use Razor's `Html.TextBoxFor()` helpers in these cases.

( I'm not sure how the `phone` list was initialized )

Comment: Thank you wii Chek and let you know

Comment: Thanks This Worked Perfectly. Cannot Up your answer as im a beginer